# My selenium code doesn't recognize flex alert windows during the runtime, it throws no alert found exception

Tags: selenium

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error" + e);
}*/
```

Also I have tried many codes , it doesn't work for me. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: can you provide the link to the webpage